# Why the local variable problem happens in python

Tags: python-3.x

I got this error

```
increment = lambda x : x + 1

def make_repeater(h, n):
    def f(x):
        value = x
        while n > 0 :
            value = h(value)
            n = n - 1

        return value
    return f
 
    a = make_repeater(increment,5)
    b = a(1)
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

while when I write like this , it runs well

```
increment = lambda x : x + 1

def make_repeater(h, n):
    def f(x):
        i = n
        value = x
        while i > 0 :
            value = h(value)
            i = i - 1

        return value
    return f
 
    a = make_repeater(increment, 5)
    b = a(1)
```

Comment: It's obvious that Python considers the `n` in the inner function to be different than the `n` in the outer function.  But I can't explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [nonlocal](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword to refer to a variable in the nearest enclosing scope. The following code, with that change, works.

```py
increment = lambda x : x + 1

def make_repeater(h, n):
    def f(x):
        nonlocal n  # <-- added this
        value = x
        while n > 0 :
            value = h(value)
            n = n - 1

        return value
    return f

a = make_repeater(increment,5)
b = a(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, if a variable in a function has the same name as a global variable, when changing the value of that variable, it will become a local variable. So the reference before the assignment problem will happen.

Comment: Use the `nonlocal` keyword to change that.

Comment: @Keith that would be worthy of an answer.  I knew about `global` but not `nonlocal`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` is not getting `n` as an argument.

Instead, `n` is taken from the scope of `make_repeater`.

As a result, in first example you work with variable `n` that is defined when the function is created, but is not availiable when the function is called.

In your second example `n` is used only during creation of the function, but when it is called it just uses the variable `i` and value `5`.